# Installing the fanuc_driver on fanuc crx robot

Tags: ros, driver, ros-melodic, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I m working on setting up the ROS Fanuc driver on  CRX 10 Ia/L robot that has a R-30ib mini plus controller
[image: image description]

Robot software is V9.40P22
[image: image description]

I used Roboguide to compile the binaries  from the ros driver following the tutorial in this link :
http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Configuration

[image: image description]

I can see the version of the robot software isn't in robo guide the closest I can find is v9.40p/23, my first question is will this cause a problem ?

Next, I loaded the programs in the controller according to the tutorial i can see them in the select program:
Karel:
[image: image description]

TP:

[image: image description]

But if run the TP programs I get these errors:
ROS state:

[image: image description]

Ros :

[image: image description]

From the ROS troubleshooting, i can see its a configuration error i re did the setup step by step but still get these errors and i want to know where exactly is the issue and if there is any remedy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399022/installing-the-fanuc_driver-on-fanuc-crx-robot/) by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you update the configuration of the Karel programs according to the values shown in the [KAREL and TPE Programs: KAREL Programs](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Configuration#KAREL_Programs) section?

The tutorial in that section states:

> The data in these two tables will need to be entered into the configuration structures of the respective programs.

and then provides instructions on how to do that.

If you did, please show a picture of the *Karel Vars* of both programs, specifically the contents of the `cfg_` variables.

> I can see the version of the robot software isn't in robo guide the closest I can find is v9.40p/23, my first question is will this cause a problem ?

No, that will not be a problem. The controller would have notified you if it was a problem (by refusing to load the `.pc` files completely).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on 2022-04-14**:
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

is this correct ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-14**:
That looks OK.

You just seem to have skipped/missed the [Complete the Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Configuration#Complete_the_Configuration) step:

> As the last step, complete the configuration by setting the `checked` entry in each of the configuration structures to `TRUE`.

**Comment by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on 2022-04-14**:
thank you, the ROS tp worked, ros relay and ros state are showing some error but probably not related to this topic I will write another question if the errors keep persisting